# Why isn't map service displaying in ArcCatalog or rest services?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, web-mapping

Update:

I have an issue where my map services, which pull ortho-imagery from a cache, intermittently do not display in my services directory, ArcCatalog or my web portal. Currently I go into ArcCatalog and click Service Properties > Caching > and check the box for Create tiles on demand, the map service will display in my rest directory for one of my services. If I check that Create tiles on demand box for another map services, I cannot see the services in the services directory inside the firewall, but I can see it outside of firewall.

This behavior is pretty strange. If anyone has dealt with a similar issue and has some idea on resolution, I would appreciate hearing from you. Yes, I am also working with Esri on this issue.

Original:

I have several map services that are not displaying the image of the service in ArcCatalog, nor are the Rest Services displaying. These map services contain ortho-imagery, which are cached at several scales, and I am certain I have been able to preview them in ArcCatalog and Rest before. In fact, I can still see the correctly cached images on my Production rest services directory. I can see coordinates when I move my mouse about in the preview window of ArcCatalog of the troublesome map services. Does anyone have a suggestion of how I can preview my map services in ArcCatalog and Rest?

I have tried:

- republishing service
- restarting server
- changing map service to display imagery dynamically rather than cached
- altering the output directories

I am using ArcGIS 10.0 and my servers are Windows Server 2008 R2 64-bit. Thanks & regards.

Comment: I had this problem on 10.0 also. Never figured out what it was. It could be permissions- if you make the folder public in manager then see them that is what it is.

Comment: Thanks, Brad. I haven't figured it out yet though I spent a couple hours on phone with Esri today. I'll post here when I figure things out.

Comment: Is the SOAP endpoint of your service configured correctly?  ArcGIS Desktop uses SOAP to connect to services.

Comment: If I remember correctly deleting the service and re-creating it was my not so elegant workaround

Comment: Craig, can you say more about the SOAP endpoint? I altered my EndPointURL in my config file but to no avail. I'm getting 404 errors in Fiddler when I scroll around map service, which isn't displaying an image, in Rest Services.

Comment: What do you see when you open the soap url `http://servername/arcgis/services/Myservice/MapServer?wsdl` in your browser?

Comment: When I open the soap url http://servername:8399/arcgis/services/Myservice/MapServer?f=jsapi I get a 404 error with a description: The requested resource is not available. I tried using the machine name as well as the IP address for the server. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually needed to recreate the cache. It took a while for me to come around to this conclusion and I really wish I knew how the tiles were deleted in the first place, but I recreated the cache and the map service is running just fine. Having my cache display a "Map data not available" png in places where there weren't any tiles got me to realize that, yep, my tiles were gone: http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2007/04/12/configuring-your-server-to-display-a-data-not-available-tile-for-empty-map-cache-areas/ 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's a matter of bandwidth in your network. I've had this issue with images from a database in the early 9. X days. It was particularly noticeable from a raster catalog. Also you mention another server, does that one have a different service? Check your caches, if they aren't built for certain levels the service will show blank when you are zoomed to that level. I just ran into that with a cached map service of imgery using Server 10.1sp1